# Add capacity to the uni-weighted graph to increase max flow

Tags: network-flow

Given a uni-weighted graph G (in which each edge has the capacity of 1), and we have k extra capacities (k is an integer) that we can spend on any subset of existing edges. That is, we can increase the capacity of any existing edges but all increases should sum up to k.
How to improve the max (s,t) flow as much as possible?

I'm considering the residual graph but it seems not that easy.
I also thought the corresponding edge-disjoint paths from s to t, however they will change after adding the capacity.

Comment: Nice problem. I do not have a good answer.  Here is one observation. If $G$ is fixed and $k$ goes to infinity, then the ratio of $k$ to max flow goes to the shortest distance from $s$ to $t$.